# DOM XML parsing null sub item

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using DOM parser with java to parse an XML string. In order to debug, I used this recursive method :

```
 public static void visitRecursively(Node node) {
        // get all child nodes
    count ++;
    System.out.println("count == " + count);

    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

        // get child node

        Node childNode = list.item(i);
    //you need to get the attributes

        NamedNodeMap attributeList = childNode.getAttributes();

      for (int j = 0; j < attributeList.getLength(); j++) {
        System.out.println("Attribute: "
                + attributeList.item(j).getNodeName() + " = "
                + attributeList.item(j).getNodeValue());
        System.out.println("Node: " + childNode.getNodeName()
        + " - with value: " + childNode.getNodeValue());

           }

        visitRecursively(childNode);
}
```

The corresponding XML is this:

```
<ObligationExpression
    ObligationId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:example:obligation:emailPermit"
    FulfillOn="Permit">
    <AttributeAssignmentExpression
        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            Your resource below has been
            accessed by:
        </AttributeValue>
    </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
</ObligationExpression>
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception at the recursive call #2.

Output:

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:example:obligation:emailPermit
count == 1
Attribute: FulfillOn = Permit
Node: ObligationExpression - with value: null
Attribute: ObligationId = urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:example:obligation:emailPermit
Node: ObligationExpression - with value: null
count == 2
```

I can't know why exactly.

Comment: Which output do you expect?

Comment: I edited the question for more precision

Answer (score 0):

You're pulling the node and the value of them but not the value of the attributes. <s>I can't test this at the moment, but this may put you on the right track.I'll revise later</s>.

```
 public static void visitRecursively(Node node) {
  // get all child nodes
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

    // Print text nodes if found
        Node childNode = list.item(i);
        if (childNode.getNodeName().equals("#text")) {
            System.out.print("Node name:" + node.getNodeName() + " ");
            System.out.print(childNode.getTextContent());
        }

        //you need to get the attributes
        NamedNodeMap attributeList = childNode.getAttributes();

//This was causing an issue, since there was text nodes, 
 //it was returning null and null does not have a length. 
        if (attributeList != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < attributeList.getLength(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Attribute: "
                        + attributeList.item(j).getNodeName() + " = "
                        + attributeList.item(j).getNodeValue());
                System.out.println("Node: " + childNode.getNodeName()
                        + " - with value: " + childNode.getNodeValue());

            }
        }

        visitRecursively(childNode);

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Node name:ObligationExpression 
Attribute: AttributeId = urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text
Node: AttributeAssignmentExpression - with value: null
Node name:AttributeAssignmentExpression 
    Attribute: DataType = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
Node: AttributeValue - with value: null
Node name:AttributeValue 
        Your resource below has been
        accessed by:
    Node name:AttributeAssignmentExpression 
Node name:ObligationExpression
```

Comment: I tried the code: it still says that my elements are empty, i'm kind of lost, why it's empty, the DOM lib is supposed to parse it all in depth..

Comment: Why do you think that an element is said to be empty? The `nodeValue` of an `Element` node in the W3C DOM is by definition `null`, see the table in http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247

Comment: Okey, but how can I get to the AttributeId and the content of the attribute value ?